# How would one configure db access for magento on AppFog

Tags: php, xml, magento, connection, appfog

i am trying to deploy megnto php app to appfog, but I need to figure out how to update db connection configuration from env variables.

I know that db connection configured in xml file under "magento/app/etc/", I also know that I should store authentication related via env variables. Question is, how would I reference them from xml file and do I need to some how let magento know about it, so when application is initialized xml processed as php file, or there is magento specific way? Any pointers, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Appfog services are automatically configured internally and their configuration is accessed via environment variables:

Try this:

```
<?php
var_dump($_ENV["VCAP_SERVICES"]);
?>
```

It should give you all the connection values you will need.

Comment: Magento uses xml file to store connection values, would xml be processed as php file for me to print db connection values?